# Capitalising Names of Industries

Tags: word-choice

"Water, Nuclear, and Oil & Gas Industries" or "water, nuclear, and oil & gas industries"

Hi, I've seen both instances been used, and I'm just looking for some clarity. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

They would not be capitalized unless they are referring to a specific company. This is because they are not proper nouns.

According to the *AP Stylebook*:

> Capitalize nouns that constitute the unique identification for a specific person, place, or thing: John, Mary, America, Boston, England. Some words, such as the examples given, are always proper nouns. Some common nouns receive proper noun status when they are used as the name of a particular entity: General Electric, Gulf Oil.